# How to ask CF9 ORM to use CHAR(2)?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

How to ask CF9 ORM (hibernate) to use CHAR(2) as sql column type?

Comment: filed bug 79628.  It seems like a bug to me.
http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=79628

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
component persistent=true {
    property name="id" fieldtype="id" ormtype="integer" generated="always" generator="identity";
    property name="char2Prop" fieldtype="column" sqltype="char(2)";
}
```